# Where is the configuration file in odoo8

Tags: python, ipython, odoo-8

I am a *PHP* developer, and I'm very new to *odoo*.

I installed  odoo8 in my local Ubuntu machine(`/var/www/html/odoo8`) using 'Source Install' method: [ref](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html)

My installation was successful and it's working fine with local PostgreSQL DB.

But I'm not able to find any configuration file in the odoo installation folder i.e. `/var/www/html/odoo8`.

Let me know, is there any configuration file for odoo, if yes, where is it? And how can  we change that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the filelist via package manager

```
dpkg-query -L odoo8
dpkg-query -L odoo8 |grep conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration file is `$HOME/. openerp_serverrc` which can be overridden using `--config`. Specifying `--save` will save the current configuration state back to that file.

Comment: thanks for your response. So by  " $HOME/." you mean my odoo installation path '/var/www/html/odoo8'  ?. If yes , i can't find any openerp_serverrc file there

Comment: when you start odoo.py from command line add --save to create the configuration file and $HOME means /home/username/

Comment: thanks for  the update.I understand what you said.But i still didn't get from where,my current odoo installation works?

Comment: if you let me see your installation steps may be I can help.

Comment: ,thanks for ur effort.1)I downloaded the  odoo ver8 source code and put in /var/www/html/odoo_test/odoo-8.0 2)In terminal ,i reach that folder and execute the command ./odoo.py 3)took the url  'http://localhost:8069/' in browser .But i didn't find the config file in this folder

Comment: After executing the command  ./odoo.py  (ie STEP 2)iam getting following out put

openerp: OpenERP version 8.0-20150917
openerp: addons paths: ['/home/linto/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/var/www/html/odoo_test/odoo-8.0/openerp/addons']
 openerp: database hostname: localhost
openerp: database port: 5432
openerp: database user: linto
openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069